# where to put configuration constant in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

I have to use a constant inside my `/app/config/environments/production.rb`. I'd like to put it somewhere as configuration constant. So I tried to put it inside an `initializer` file, but `/app/config/environments/production.rb` seems to be loaded before. Then I tried to put my constant inside `Rails::Initializer.run do |config|...` inside the `/app/config/environment.rb`, but `/app/config/environments/production.rb` still seems to be loaded before. Where can I put propermy this constant as a config constant so that `/app/config/environments/production.rb` recognizes it ?

Comment: Try this for managing configuration in your application: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Comment: Assuming you only need this constant in production, can you not just define the constant at the top of `config/environments/production.rb`? If you need it in more than just production, you can define it at the top of `config/environment.rb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make it clear what is the path you walk through to your app loads the initilization files. You must have in mind this :

When you run `rails s` (from your `app/script/rails` file) that runs `rails` server,

- your app `boot.rb` file (which mainly deals with gems loading) is required and then your console `args` (here the `server` alias `s`) requirement is passed to the `rails` `railties/lib/rails/command.rb` file (which is in the `rails` source code).
- There, your app `config/application.rb` is required. Then, the `Server` class is instantiated and you are thrown in `railties/lib/rails/command/server.rb` file. In fact, the `Server` class inhererits from `Rack::Server`, so a `rails` app is `rack` app ! So, you'll find a `config.ru` file in your `rails` app and this loads the `config/environment.rb` file.

The `config/environment.rb` file does two things

- requiring your app `config/applcation.rb`, that loads the proper `rails framework`.( For info, you'll find in your app `application.rb` the `Application` class that inherits from `Rails::Application`, which inherits itself from the `Rails::Engine`, which inherits from a `Rails::Railtie` class)
- calling the `initialize!` bang method, that loads the `config/environment/*.rb` files, and then processes all the initializers process (more precisely, the initializers methods are defined in the `railties/lib/rails/engine.rb`) file. So, now, taking that into account, you should be able to define properly your constants.

To better understand the intialization process, I recommand you this great [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/299-rails-initialization-walkthrough?autoplay=true), which mainly inspired this answer.